# Google App Engine import NLTK error

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, nltk

I am trying to import NLTK library in Google App Engine it gives error, I created another module "testx.py" and this module works without error but I dont know why NLTK does not work.

My code 
nltk_test.py

```
import webapp2
import path_changer
import testx
import nltk

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        #self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write("TEST")

class nltkTestPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        text = nltk.word_tokenize("And now for something completely different")
        self.response.write(testx.test("Hellooooo"))


application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage), ('/nltk', nltkTestPage),
], debug=True)
```

testx.py code

```
def test(txt):
    return len(txt)
```

path_changer.py code

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'nltk'))
sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'new'))
```

app.yaml

```
application: nltkforappengine
version: 0-1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:

- url: /.*
  script: nltk_test.application
- url: /nltk.*
  script: nltk_test.application

libraries:
- name: numpy
  version: "1.6.1"
```

This code works fine When I comment the import nltk and nltk related code, I think NLTK is not imported, please help me to sort out this problem, thanks

Comment: HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you have nltk installed?

GAE libraries need to be available in your app folder.  If you have nltk elsewhere in your pythonpath it won't work.

Comment: why do you need the path_changer code?  that seems kinda odd in the GAE environment.